# Update custom Date Field if new opportunity stage is "Cold" OR previous opportunity stage was "Early Negotiation"

Tags: workflow, opportunity

Is there a way to accomplish this with a workflow instead of a trigger? I would like to update a custom date field (**Opportunity Stage Change**) to TODAY() whenever the new opportunity stage is **Cold** OR whenever the priorvalue is **Early Negotiation**.Either way would work for me. I have seen a few solutions with trigger but I'm trying to get this done using either a Workflow or Process Builder.

Here is what I got for the workflow but I'm doing it wrong:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName ) = 'Cold',
              (IF(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE( StageName ) , 'Early Negotiation'),  Opportunity_Stage_Change__c = TODAY(), null),null)
```

I'm getting the following error, but I think there is a bigger problem with the logic/approach.

> Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Comment: i counted your number of parenthesis and they dont seem to add up, so, the error message is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Also important, you're not calling the `ISPICKVAL()` function correctly (it takes two parameters), and you can't assign the `Opportunity_Stage_Change__c ` field IN the formula. Use a Workflow Rule Field Update to do that piece.

Comment: Have you created a duplicate account? I am pretty sure I've seen a very similar username/avatar combo. Please don't maintain multiple accounts.  You can [contact](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) the community team to get your accounts merged.

Comment: I haven't, Adrian. I deactivated my account in the past and just logged back in.

Comment: @glls Yes. I know, but I really looking for a help like David Reed provided. Thought that was pretty self explanatory with my last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to use the formula function reference tools (either in the documentation or within the formula editor) to check how you use each function, and make sure you're providing the right number and type of parameters.

Any time you use words like "and" and "or" in describing your objectives, you'll probably find the `AND()` and `OR()` functions in your formula. Here, you need an `OR()`.

You probably want to use a formula like this to decide whether your Workflow Rule or Process Builder is executed:

```
OR(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Cold'), ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName) , 'Early Negotiation'))
```

Then the actions you provide in Process Builder or WFR handle the assignment of the value `TODAY()` to your custom field. You can't perform assignment (or, indeed, make any data changes) within a formula